# What is the best practice for center aligning inline elements within a div?

Tags: css, html

For example if I have a parent div and 5 images I want to have centered within that div with a little margin around the images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the text-align css value on the container:

```
div {
text-align: center;
}
```

And apply the margin to each of the images inside:

```
div img {
margin: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this: http://jsfiddle.net/QrgGH/1/ substitue the divs for img nodes

Comment: I'm sure it doesn't matter, but my images are side by side and it didn't work for me :/  

.divName {
 position: absolute;
}
.div img{
 border: 4px solid #fff;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 5px;
 position: relative;

Comment: side by side? are you floating them? whats the width of the parent div? go ahead and post your html and css code so we can have a look

Comment: let me just say it works fine when I just text-align: center; the parent div.  I just don't know if that's the proper way to do it.  This is my html/css: 
`<div class="test">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
</div>`
`.div {
 text-align: center;
}
.div img{
 border: 4px solid #fff;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 5px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="images">
     <img src="#" alt="">
     <img src="#" alt="">
     <img src="#" alt="">
   </div>
</div>

img{max-width: 100%; height: auto;}
.container{text-align:center;}
.images{margin: 5px;}
```

Read some information about block and inline elements